# Integrate google plus circles in app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-plus

I was wondering if there is a way to use google+ in a app engine app to create circles, add people in circles and push posts to circles?

So for example a user logs in to my app, the app can then add/remove people from circles depending on the users setting within my app.

If that is not possible is there a least a way to access who is in a users circles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot do any of the three things you asked about: cannot create circles, cannot modify or even read circle data, and cannot write the user's stream.

While who is circled or circled by a user is shown in the user's Google+ profile (if they've made that public), you cannot tell what circles those people are in or what they are called. Circle names and who are in them are private data.

The only API that comes close to what you're interested in is the [History API](https://developers.google.com/+/history/), which allows you to share moments to a user's Google+ history that they can then choose to share to their stream.

**Edit 8/14/2013**: If you are using a [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/), the new [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) offers the functions that you desire. You can only manage users within the domain and you can only make posts that are restricted to your domain (no public posts or posts to users outside of the domain).

Comment: Is there any update regarding creating circles or modifying circles ?

Comment: Updated my answer with new information regarding the Google+ Domains API release.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no publicly documented API that lets you read or manage your circles.

There is a limited access API, which Google has made available to some developers. See https://plus.google.com/104946722942277428266/posts/LUi2ZNyRHag for more information about what is coming and how you can sign up to request access to this.