# circles().list command giving error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-plus

We are creating an appengine project that would check if the user uses Google+. To do so I would like to see how many people a user has added to his/her circle.
However, the circles().list command does not seem to work.

I execute the following code:

```
final List<String> scope = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.media.upload","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write");

GoogleCredential credential2 = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport).setServiceAccountScopes(scope).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL).setServiceAccountUser(EMAIL_ADMIN).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(PATH_TO_P12_FILE)).build();

PlusDomains plusDomains = new PlusDomains.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setHttpRequestInitializer(credential2).setApplicationName("APPNAME").setRootUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/").build();

Person person = plusDomains.people().get(user.getId()).execute();
if(person.getCircledByCount() > 0) {
PlusDomains.Circles.List listCircles = plusDomains.circles().list(user.getId());
listCircles.setMaxResults(5L);
CircleFeed circlefeed = listCircles.execute();
}
```

However, upon the last execute() the application returns an 403-error code (forbidden).

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some API permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently access Google+ circle data or modify it through AppEngine or otherwise, as that would involve accessing a lot of private user data.

The closest thing you could use is the [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) if you currently use [Google Apps](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/), however that is restricted to only managing and posting to within a particular domain (it's designed for internal business networking rather than for general consumer usage)

**(EDIT 27/01/2015)**: After posting this I saw there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725415/integrate-google-plus-circles-in-app-engine) with a more in-depth answer, and though it is 2 years old the policies haven't changed.